# ngCordova writeFile does not exist on type File error

Tags: cordova, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2, ngcordova

I am building an Ionic2 app and I have successfully managed to create a local file using the 'ngCordova' plugin.

However, the function writeFile(..) listed on: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/
doesn't seem to be supported by the same plugin which I used to create the same file.

This is the piece of code that is not working.

```
File.writeFile(this.getFilePath(), 'feedback.txt', data, true);
```

where File.writeFile is highligted with a message '**Unresolved function or method writeFile'**.

When I build my app. the error that appears is:

```
Error TS2339: Property 'writeFile' does not exist on type 'typeOf File'
```

Any ideas if the Cordova plugin no longer supports this function or if the function is succeeded by another one, which I can't seem to be able to find?

Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone know? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic 2 doesn't use ngCordova, instead it uses [Ionic Native](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/).

Ionic Native has it's own [File](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/) wrapper class but this is currently missing the `.writeFile()` implementation, track the related GitHub issue here [#264](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/264)

For now you can use the [`.createFile()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/#createFile) method of the Ionic Native File wrapper which should return a `fileEntry` object in the promise allowing you use some native file plugin code to write to the file.

**Example**

```
File.createFile(this.getFilePath(), 'feedback.txt', true).then((fileEntry) => {

    fileEntry.createWriter((fileWriter) => {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = () => {
            console.log('File writer - write end event fired...');
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = (e) => {
            console.log('file writer - error event fired: ' + e.toString());
        };

        fileWriter.write(data);
    });
```

**Update**

I believe the File class now has a [`.writeFile()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/#writeFile) method which should be used instead of my example code, but I haven't gotten around to trying it yet.

Comment: Actually it does not appear to be implemented yet... unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Jens. I saw it appear in the latest documentation (see the link for .writeFile()) and assumed it would now be working